# What became of Rhaegar's corpse after Robert killed him?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

After Robert killed Rhaegar on the Trident, the loyalist army fled in disarray.

What happened to Prince Rhaegar's body? Did it float away along the River? Or was it recovered by the fleeing loyalists? Or did the rebels capture the body?

How was Rhaegar Targaryen's end writ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rhaegar's corpse was cremated according to Targaryen customs.

From the Citadel:

> Q: [What happened to Rhaegar's body?]
>
> GRRM: Rhaegar was cremated, as is traditional for fallen Targaryens.
> <sub>***[The Citadel: SSM - Asshai.com chat](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/2997/)***</sub>

Since Targaryen funeral rites were respected, it seems likely that the loyalists managed to recover the corpse whether via force or as a gesture of respect from the Rebels. Given how much Robert hated Rhaegar, it is unlikely that he would have returned the corpse had he gotten his hands on it. He may have preferred to mutilate his corpse or something of that sort. It seems more plausible that the loyalists recovered the corpse before fleeing or someone among the Rebel lords quietly handed over the corpse while Robert was recovering from the wounds he took.

There is however no canon evidence about any of that. We just know that Rhaegar's end was writ in flames, like all Targaryens before him.

Comment: I could imagine Eddard either performing the rite or handing over the body while Robert was out of action. It seems like both a sensible and an honourable course of action, especially given Ned doesn't seem to harbour any of the negative feeling toward Rhaegar that Robert displays. The war was pretty much won, Ned would be focused on how they rebuild the bridges between the two sides, and Robert desecrating Rhaegar's corpse likely would have been a hindrance to that effort.

Comment: @delinear It is a possibility but Word would have spread like rumors flew about Ned and Ashara. Soldiers talk. And then Robert would have been enraged. Only time Robert and Ned had a quarrel was when Lannisters killed Rhaegar's kids and Robert felt no pity or remorse. And remember, Trident happened when even Ned thought Rhaegar had abducted Lyanna. Of course afterwards he went to ToJ and we don't know what Lyanna told him but certainly she told the truth. War could have still gone either way if Tywin Lannister had joined Aerys instead of betraying him, so it wasn't a done thing yet